# Conditional load polyfills using webpack with chunkhash

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have followed the instructions [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills) to conditionally load a polyfills file only in old browsers, having the following script in my index.html:

```html
<script>
  const modernBrowser = (
    'fetch' in window &&
    'assign' in Object
  );
  if (!modernBrowser) {
    const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.async = false;
    scriptElement.src = '/polyfills.js';
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
  }
</script>
```

But then on production we move the files to `js` folder and add a `chunckhash` to the name to avoid catching problems. That's the webpack output configuration:

```javascript
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    polyfills: './src/pollyfills.js',
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  }
}
```

The problem: This will generate a polyfills file such as `js/polyfills.620f3ed184b15f38c3f9.js`but on the script I'm loading `/polyfills.js` that doesn't exist. How can I can properly set the value of `scriptElement.src` after webpacking to point to the correct file?

Answer (score -2):

you can use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to serve the chunkhash file.